# PHP скрипт не работает на UTF-16

Tags: php, кодировка, unicode

Как-то ранее я обращался с маленьким вопросом по поводу скрипта отправки на почту. Проблема теперь возникла в том, что при смене кодировки на UTF-16 (а ранее была win1251) скрипт отказывается работать. Я удивлен.

Каким-то образом перестает идентифицироваться как скрипт, та часть скрипта, что идет после "echo" и соответственно концовка скрипта

Подскажите, что можно сделать, чтобы вновь вернуть его к жизни?

```
<?php
// если была нажата кнопка "Отправить"
if($_POST['submit']) {
        $title = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['title'])), 0, 1000);
$milo = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['milo'])), 0, 1000);
$fon = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fon'])), 0, 100);
$mess =  "Новое сообщение в форме заказа!\n\nТекст заказа:\n\n" . 

substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['mess'])), 0, 1000000) ."\n\nадрес отправившего:\n\n". $milo "\n\nТелефон отправившего:\n\n". $fon . "\n\nКонец текста.". "\n\nЭто письмо сгенерировано автоматически!";
        $to = 'мой e-mail';

        // $from - от кого
        $from=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        mail($to, $title, $mess, 'From:'.$from);
        echo("<script>location.href='http://моя glavanaya stranica'</script>");
} ?>
```

UTF-16 необходим для того, чтобы использовать специфические символы, которых нет в win1251.

Comment: Попробуйте utf-8. 

IMHO utf-16 это не текстовый формат (в нем символы кодируются парой байт) и у всех ascii  один из 2-х байт будет нулевым.

Comment: в utf-8 результат примерно такой: РћР±СЂР°С‚РЅР°СЏ СЃРІСЏР·СЊ
вместо спец. символов знаки вопроса. просто русские буквы понимает. но из других языков - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то в кодировке UTF-16 у вас сам исполняемый скрипт? В этом случае необходимо:

1. Убедится, что PHP был собран с опцией [--enable-zend-multibyte](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php#configure.enable-zend-multibyte)
2. Установить в `php.ini` параметры:

   - [`zend.multibyte`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.multibyte) `= 1`
   - [`zend.script_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.script-encoding) `= UTF-16`

После этого скрипты в UTF-16 будут парсится и, соответственно, интерпритироваться корректно.

**UPD.** Кроме того учтите, что эти параметры влияют только на парсинг самих скриптов. Они не избавляют вас от необходимости учитывать кодировку входящих и исходящих данных.

Другими словами, вам по прежнему необходимо пользоваться расширением `mbstring` для работы со строками, задавать `SET NAMES utf16` при коннекте к MySQL, отправлять заголовок `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-16` при формировании HTML-файлов и т.д.

Comment: php.ini создавать в корне сайта?

Comment: Расположение [`php.ini`](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), можно узнать вызвав функцию [`phpinfo()`](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). Там же можно проверить скомпилирован PHP с опцией `--enable-zend-multibyte` или нет.

Comment: в этом и причина, что часть скрипта не понимается как скрипт?

Comment: Ну сохраните вы скрипт с одним лишь вызовом `<?php phpinfo()` в UTF-8 или любой однобайтовой кодировке и посмотрите где у вас php.ini

PS Мой вам совет - бросайте вы это дело...

Comment: не могу воспользоваться Вашим советом - обстоятельства не позволяют. но, в любом случае, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте multibyte. Функции в большинстве своем аналогичные тем, которые созданы для работы со строками, но перед названием префикс mb_.
Например, [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php)

[@avp](/users/232/avp), utf-8 еще более коварный: он выдает внезапные ошибки, где их совсем не ждешь. Пример, буква ё в регулярных выражениях.
Так что его, конечно, использовать хорошо, но на всем, кроме 100% 8битных аски-совместимых лучше использовать mb_

Напомню, utf-8 лишь СОВМЕСТИМ с 8битным кодированием.

Comment: да проблема здесь у меня не совсем в substring... о содержимом письма я еще не думал...











обычно всё, что написано под заголовком php на странице невидимо, а тут вдруг на странице на всеобщее обозрение проявляется кусок скрипта 



location.href='http://моя glavanaya stranica'</script>");
} ?>




т.е. то, что написано после слова <script>
и соответственно, переход на главную страничку уже не работает, не работает и отправка письма вообще. такой глюк только в utf-16. при переводе в utf-8 вместо спец. символов знаки вопроса.

Comment: @knes, а в какой кодировке в регулярных выражениях, считающих, что русские буквы в диапазоне от А до я нет проблем с ёЁ ?

Что Вы имеете в виду под "СОВМЕСТИМ с 8битным кодированием" ? 

UTF-8 позволяет кодировать все 31-бит (т.е. неотрицательные) числа (весь UCS).

Comment: @Venya_Pupkoff
1) substring я привел для примера. Слева на той же станице полный список функций. 

@avp, 
1) с диапазонами проблема у всех. Но у UTF-8 еще и с расширенными диапазонами [а-яА-ЯёЁ] проблема. И это только то, что пришло в голову. Я ни в коем случае ничего не имею против utf-8. Я лишь указываю, что переход на него всего чуть-чуть менее болезненный, чем на любую другую мультибайтовую кодировку.
2) он (к счастью. Но от этого в данном контексте не легче) не является 8битным. Но в некоторой степени совместим с ним.
3) см вторую часть пункта 1.

Comment: а почему не работает функция 
echo("<script>location.href='http://моя glavanaya stranica'</script>");
} ?>
?

Comment: Для начала, попробуйте наоборот(поменял местами двойные кавычки и одинарные):  

    echo('<script>location.href="http://моя glavanaya stranica"</script>'); } ?>

Есть подозрение, что где-то попадаются кавычки(при кодировании) или что-то вроде.

Comment: не помогает((
всё нормально распознается до слова <script>, после -нет

http://narod.ru/disk/55237843001.163930b61f8cc641f1239d305b4c2920/kode.jpg.html

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте открыть ваш скрипт в Notepad++ и посмотреть кодировку и пересохранить в UTF-8 без BOM  или UTF-16 без BOM